# Fetching the TIMEVALUE from Date/Time datatype

Tags: datetime, formula-field, date

My Scenario is, I am having two fields as Startdatetime_*c(date/time) & LastDatetime(date/time). Here another one field Nextdatetime*_c(date/time Formula field) i want the Date from LastDatetime_*c(date/time) and time from Startdatetime*_c(date/time).I tried the following:

```
DATEVALUE(LastDatetime__c) & TIMEVALUE(Startdatetime__c)
```

But it throws the error as Error:

> Unknown function TIMEVALUE. Check spelling.

How to resolve this?

Comment: Check [this](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BqVkAAK). Seemslike `TIMEVALUE` is still not available. Also how you are going to generate the datetime field here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there are no standard functions for that. You will have to build the 
datetime value from separate strings like this:

DATETIMEVALUE(TEXT(DATEVALUE(LastDatetime_c))&" "&MID(TEXT(Startdatetime_c),12,8))

Comment: Thanks for your comment @guy, i try your logic inside the formula editor but it throws the error as "YEAR()'. Expected Date, received DateTime" because am using Date/Time datatype for Formula field..

Comment: You are right. I tested this with a date field. I updated my answer accordingly. Actually it becomes better, since TEXT(DATEVALUE()) returns the date in the correct format for  DATETIMEVALUE()

Comment: Thanks for your support @guy "DATETIMEVALUE(TEXT(DATEVALUE(LastDatetime_c))&" "&MID(TEXT(Startdatetime_c),12,8))" this part works perfectly..

Comment: Hi @guy one help in this formula logic Days__c(Text)
Formula: DATETIMEVALUE(TEXT(DATEVALUE(LastDatetime_c)+Days__c)&" "&MID(TEXT(Startdatetime_c),12,8))
INputs : Startdatetime_c = 20/03/2014 10:00 ,LastDatetime_c = 27/03/2014 10:00 Days__c = 8  Result : Nextdatetime_c = 04/03/2014 11:00 (Here time increased as 1 hour)
User timezone & Organization timezones are same GMT+00:00 Europe/London
If the month is move from MAR to APR then the hour will be increased, if the month is in MAR means the time should be perfect..

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.newInstance(LastDatetime__c.year(), LastDatetime__c.month(), LastDatetime__c.day(), Startdatetime__c.hour(), Startdatetime__c.minute(), Startdatetime__c.second());
```

Have a look in the docs at [datetime methods](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Richard here i need a Formula logic for the above question, not as apex code.Am implementing formula field logic.Is there any other ways to implement inside the Formula Editor?